# Cómo hago una declaración correcta de un vector de estructuras en c++?

Tags: c++, estructuras, array

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Cómo declaro correctamente un vector de estructuras?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct Cliente {
    int DNI;
    string Nombre;
    string Apellido;
    int telefono;
};
//Vector de estructuras:
vector<Cliente> Clientes(100);
//Funcion para rellenar el vector...
void Nuevo_Cliente(vector<Cliente>& c) {
    cin >> c[0].DNI;
    cin >> c[0].Nombre;
    cin >> c[0].Apellido;
}

int main() {
    Clientes c;
    Nuevo_Cliente(c);
    cout << Clientes[0] << endl;
}
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es introducir datos de un cliente en una "base de datos". Esta parte de código es sólo para introducir los datos de UN SÓLO cliente.
Quiero que el programa permita insertar la diferente información del cliente y lo guarde en su respectiva posicion del vector, comenzando desde la 0 a, como máximo la 100.
Todo funciona correctamente hasta que llego a la funcion "Nuevo_Cliente", que es la que se encarga de los cin. El problema no está en la función en si, sino en cómo la declaro en la función "main()". Cuando compilo me salta el siguiente error: "c was not declared in this scope" y "expected ';' before 'c'.

Si alguien sabe cómo puedo declarar la funcion "Nuevo_Cliente" dentro de la función "main()" o escribiría el codigo de otra manera, que no dude en contestar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale chicos, tengo la respuesta. Os dejo aquí el codigo totalmente funcional:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct Cliente {
    int DNI;
    string Nombre;
    string Apellido;
    int telefono;
};
//Vector de estructuras:
vector<Cliente> Clientes(100);
//Funcion para rellenar el vector...
void Nuevo_Cliente(vector<Cliente>& c) {
    cin >> c[0].DNI;
    cin >> c[0].Nombre;
    cin >> c[0].Apellido;
    cin >> c[0].telefono;
}

int main() {
    Nuevo_Cliente(Clientes);
    cout << Clientes[0].DNI << endl;
}
```